# Action cable unable to connect (Failed to upgrade to WebSocket )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I am having a issue in connecting to websocket in non-development environments with these log messages

```
Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: close, HTTP_UPGRADE: )

Finished "/cable/"[non-WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-06 09:44:29 +1000
```

I debuggged a little and figured out the request sent by the browser/javascript is not exactly the same as the request received by unicorn(running with nginx).

The request header by the browser is

```
GET ws://cc-uat.com.au/cable HTTP/1.1
Host: cc-uat.com.au
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: http://cc-uat.com.au
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cookie: <Lot of cookies>
Sec-WebSocket-Key: QGdJkYIA2u7vtmMVXfHKtQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: actioncable-v1-json, actioncable-unsupported
```

The connection here is 'upgrade' but the websocket request has the connection 'closed'(probably nginx is messing it up?)

And this piece of code in websocket driver is failing

```
def self.websocket?(env)
      connection = env['HTTP_CONNECTION'] || ''
      upgrade    = env['HTTP_UPGRADE']    || ''

      env['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' and
      connection.downcase.split(/ *, */).include?('upgrade') and
      upgrade.downcase == 'websocket'
end
```

Updates

This is my nginx configuration

```
upstream app {
    server unix:/home/osboxes/sites/actioncable-examples/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /home/osboxes/sites/actioncable-example/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }


    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

I have mounted actioncable server on /cable

```
mount ActionCable.server => "/cable"
```

With the nginx changes i am able to successfully have the handshake but the server is not able to send the heart beats and the connection keeps dropping.

```
Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-07 05:48:06 +0100
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-07-07 05:48:06 +0100
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
```

Comment: What version of Nginx are you running? I think WebSockets are supported since 1.3. Did you set `Upgrade` and `Connection` headers as https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/ suggests?

Comment: updated question !!   @JuliuszGonera

Comment: This works for me with Nginx 1.7.12: https://gist.github.com/jgonera/91aa8c1f4e38bf0169ccc3adc00be90c

Comment: Thanks @JuliuszGonera my nginx configuration is working..but still not with unicorn it works with puma .. Whats your unicorn version?

Comment: Confirmed 2 things need to be done. As mentioned in the answer below, you need to set the `config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins`. Also, if your app is running behind nginx proxy, you need to proxy_set_header as mentioned by @juliuszGonera. See also nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html.

Comment: @sethi When using Unicorn does the connection fail to upgrade to WebSocket or is it a different problem?

Comment: If you still have problems with Unicorn (in development) this might be the reason: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26179

Answer (score 3):

Have you set the `config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins` in production.rb to allow connections from your production domain?
In my nginx.conf there is also

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;  
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
```

I am not entirely sure if they are really required, but it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Rails 5 Action Cable CORS:**

create a ruby file i.e `action_cable.rb` in `my_rails_project/config/initializers` and add the following code.

```
if Rails.env.development?
  Rails.application.config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins =  ['http://localhost:3001', 'http://127.0.0.1:3001']
end
```

you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38314587/5706413) i was getting the similar error. Issue was that i kept backend url address in `config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins` on changing it to frontend url issue got resolved. To be more clear i am having font-end,backend in entirely different domains